# 3 Questions: include header/footer file, varchar as pk, switch languages

Tags: php, mysql

**Under MVC model considerations**

1.Include header/footer file

Is it common to include header or footer file to reuse code?
However I have a question:If I have several css/js files that need to add to head of header file,and they may not always the same in different controllers.And I don't want to add them all to the head. How can I do?

2. Varchar as pk?

Assume I have a table '**users**' and have an autoincrement integer column **id** and a varchar column as **username** which is unique. Actually, I always use the username for searching data. Is it worth to get back the id by username and then use the id for sql operation? It is better to set the username as pk?

3.Language switch

Assume I have a table '**catagories**' which include a column **name** and it is in English form. The name will be printed on the website. How can I switch language?

I have thought a solution, that is the name act as a variable name but not a true data.
Such as the name store a variable name called cat_product dnd then use it as $lang['cat_product']='Product';

Is it a good method?

Comment: Hi there @Steven. If you could write your questions so they are of wide interest to future readers, that helps a lot here. That means splitting questions into one topic per post. I appreciate this format takes a little getting used to, but we're not a forum or a chat room - we're collating useful questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes it is common practice to reuse the header and footer to minimize code replication, however, nothing stops you from keeping that to a strict minimum, then computing and appending elements and style to our footer and header according to which page you are on.
2. Even if the username is unique, it is still better practice to use a unique id to identify a user in your table, simply because they will be faster to compare for your SQL engine.
3. Common practice for a website with different languages is to load the language from the users pref files (or from a config files), and use variables instead of plain text everywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. At the controller, before you load your view (where i suppose where is load the header/footer) you can load an array with the scripts you'll need in each controller, and a PHP loop at header/footer.php where you print the `<script></script>` tags for each position.
2. Always it's better a numeric autoincremental id instead varchar. Code complexity increase a bit when you must generate new codes in a varchar. If you can use int id, do it.
3. I used to have several files `es_<file>.php`, `en_<file>.php`, etc... with the same variables and same content in different languages. Then you just load the file you need and use the vars at your will.